# add,remove and list Cpanel Addon domain by php

Tags: php, api, cpanel

I surf the web and find Cpanel has got some php API to do it.

but I can't find where should I download this API,only I found document.

where can I download it?

Answer (score 0):

Cpanel XML api is avaliable via githut in this link https://github.com/CpanelInc/xmlapi-php